# VB.NET SQL Server Select Count(*) - ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have my code VB.NET code for the login page like this:

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click

    Try
        If UsernameTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Insert your username.")
            UsernameTextBox.Focus()
            Return
        ElseIf PasswordTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Insert your Passwprd.")
            PasswordTextBox.Focus()
            Return
        Else
            Dim count As Integer
            Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=JUNIOR-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ShopHereNow")
                con.Open()
                Dim command = New OleDbCommand("Select count(*) from Employees where FirstName = '" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and [Password] = '" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'")
                count = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
                If count > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Welcome " & UsernameLabel.Text & "!")
                    Me.Hide()
                    Home.Show()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid combination. Try again...")
                    Cancel.PerformClick()
                    Return
                End If
            End Using
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR5", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

On executing this code i get the error reading: `ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized`

Please help, where could I have coded a mistake?

Comment: You need to link your command to your connection, such as `command.Connection = con` before you call the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have some mistakes,

1. Use `Parameterized Queries` :

   ```
   Dim command = New OleDbCommand("Select count(*) from Employees where FirstName =@FirstName and Password = @Password")
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", UsernameTextBox.Text)
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordTextBox.Text)
   ```

This is to avoid `SQL Injection Attack` AKA `For Security`

2. The error mentioned above is because you haven't specify the connection in your command, change your `Dim command = New OleDbCommand("Select count(*) from Employees where FirstName =@FirstName and Password = @Password")` to `Dim command = New OleDbCommand("Select count(*) from Employees where FirstName =@FirstName and Password = @Password", **con**)`
3. `MsgBox()` is a deprecated method, use `MessegeBox.Show()` instead.
4. Do not use Class `Exception`. Instead specify the specific Exception type. In here, you may need `SQLException`

Comment: Is there a warning in VS that MsgBox() is a deprecated method? I don't remember it being a deprecated method. I only know that MessageBox.Show() is more preferred because you can use it in C# easily. MsgBox() is only available in C# if you import the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace. VB projects import this namespace by default.

Comment: Thanks so much I have done the changes you mentioned and the error is solved. However, how will i get the value of my variable 'count' in my code above?

Comment: @KeithJnrP.Mthembu : You are welcome. But I don't get it. What is the problem now ? Program should work fine.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen : Thanks for notification. Actually there isn't a warning about a deprecation. Its that I read it somewhere. I actually don't remember the source but thanks for enlightenment. :)